# Python - Networkx : Creating a graph for given set of nodes

Tags: python-3.x, graph, nodes, networkx

Let `c4_leaves = [61, 84, 122, 146]`. I'm trying to create a complete graph of 4 nodes by taking each element of `c4_leaves` as a node. I've tried the following:

```
    V_ex = c4_leaves
    #print('V_ex',V_ex)
    G_ex = nx.Graph() 
    G_ex.add_nodes_from(list(V_ex))
    G_ex = nx.complete_graph(len(V_ex))
    print('gnodes',list(G_ex.nodes()))
```

But when I print the `G_ex.nodes()`, it returns me `[0,1,2,3]` except `[61, 84, 122, 146]`.

I tried `G_ex = nx.complete_graph(len(c4_leaves))` and `G_ex = nx.complete_graph(4)`, but didn't work.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried `G_ex = nx.complete_graph(c4_leaves)` ?

Comment: @JonClements, Input should be the number of nodes as `G_ex = nx.complete_graph(len(c4_leaves))`.And I tried this too. Didn't work.

Comment: The docs for `help(nx.complete_graph)` for me show *int or iterable container of nodes
    If n is an integer, nodes are from range(n).
    If n is a container of nodes, those nodes appear in the graph.*

Comment: What version of networkx are you using? The latest is 2.2 and the docs you linked is for 1.1..

Comment: For instance: `list(nx.complete_graph([5, 10, 15, 20]).edges())` gives me `[(5, 10), (5, 15), (5, 20), (10, 15), (10, 20), (15, 20)]`...